# Dynamically changing the content of a web page with a request from another backend

Tags: websocket, tcp, frontend, microservices, backend

I want to change the content of a web page dynamically or display a completely different page with a request from another backend.

**Use case:**
I go to the address http://localhost:8000/
Server1 responded to me the page1
Page1 is opened on my browser
Server2 act like a switch and make a request to server1
**My screen should be updated and I should see page2**

BUT
I cannot create a proper structure and don't know how I can do this.
Maybe I should use WebSocket however I am not sure

Here is my diagram
[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZqWl.png)

I tried to fetch incoming requests in frontend
I tried to use WebSocket

Comment: Basically you need to use AJAX with custom business logic on server1. You can't sent a full page redirect response dynamically from a server AFAIK.